# FHIR: return a list of patient resource based on last

Tags: hl7-fhir

Need some advice and help from you!

Two questions.

1. how can I retrieve a list of patient resources with 30 _counts and sorted by last modified date? I don't have any searching parameters such as identifier, family and given;
2. since my application in browser is a single page application, when the user scroll down and all the first 30 patients have been shown, I will make another call to get the next 30 patients. I don't need the first 30 patients and just want the records from 31 to 60. What parameters should I used in this paging search? Do we have something like "?_count=30&**_page=2**". Similarly, if I need the page 100, I don't want the servers sending me the first 99 pages.

Thanks in advance.
Autorun

Answer (score 2):

GET [baseUrl]/Patient?_count=30&sort=_lastUpdated

The response will be a Bundle.  Look at the Bundle.link with a Bundle.link.relation of "next".  The Bundle.link.url will be the URL to use to get the next "page" of content.  The format of the URL is undefined and will be server-specific.

Be aware that _count only constrains the base resource.  If you query Patient and do a _revinclude on Observation, you'll get 30 patients - but you'll also get all the observations for all 30 of those patients - which could be 10k+ rows in your result set - so be careful with _include and _revinclude.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. Do you have any suggestion about question 2, i.e. get the bundle by the exact page only? If I want page 3, I want the records in the bundle from record 61 to 90 only (30 records per page).

Comment: It's not possible - at least not using mechanisms defined in the spec.  For some query mechanisms, jumping to a random position in the result set is hard.  So we only support navigating to next page, previous page, first page and last page.

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie, sorry. but you are wrong. You can use "?_count=X&_page=Y" (checked on DSTU-2), and pages count calculated automatically by formula: (searchset.total/query _count param)
  As example i send request: [base]/Observation?_format=json&_count=2
  and as result FHIR server return me searchset with 2 entries and next properties: total=50465,  last page "page=25232"

Comment: The _page parameter is not defined in any version of FHIR (DSTU1, DSTU2 or STU3) and there are no plans to add such a parameter.  It's possible some servers may have implemented a parameter like that, but that's outside the FHIR spec and not something you can count on in general.

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie I have seen on many servers that [baseUrl]/[type] endpoint sends a collection of resources let us say, patients. I need to know that I have not seen this behavior is described in the read operation section. Is, this is a fhir official behavior?

If this is a fhir official behavior then what fhir says about the count of the resources that should be returned when one hit the url [baseUrl]/[type]?

Comment: When you hit [baseUrl]/[type] you're performing a query with no filter.  It's up to the server to decide how many rows you get back, though you're free to use _count to further constrain this.